# How to generate ASN1 format on PHP

Tags: php, phpseclib, asn.1

I'm working with smart card's and i need to generate ASN1 format something like below and encode them  RSASSA-PSS but i don't know how to do that on php v5.6(debian).

```
IdentityIdentificationStaticData ::= SEQUENCE
{
  acceptedPolicyVersion [0] DataObjectVersionNumber,
  cardHolderID          [1] CardHolderIdentifier,
  deviceSerialNumber    [2] CardAccessDeviceSerialNumber,
  appLabel              [3] UTF8String,
  requestorRole         [4] ServiceRequestorRole,
  creationTime          [5] UTCTime
}

IdentityIdentificationDataObject::= [APPLICATION 7] SEQUENCE
{
  identityIdentificationData [0] IdentityIdentificationData,
  samSignature               [1] DataObjectDigitalSignature
}

IdentityIdentificationData::= SEQUENCE
{
  version          [0] DataObjectVersionNumber,
  staticData       [1] IdentityIdentificationStaticData
}
```

I'm try to use phpseclib but couldn't figgure out how to do.

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/sop/asn1) ?

Comment: @ka_lin Tnx but. 
Requirements
PHP >=7.0
I already look that
And i want to do that myself if is it possible

Comment: https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-201508-I/en is the spec for BER/CER/DER (you likely want DER). Some of what you need to know comes from X.680 (ASN.1 language)

Comment: i did it on this [link](http://asn1-playground.oss.com/)  I use a map like i write. Its worked. But i can't do it on php @bartonjs

Comment: I generally monitor the phpseclib tag on SO but missed this since it didn't have the phpseclib tag added to it. Anyway, per https://stackoverflow.com/q/49421661/569976, it looks like you figured this out?

Comment: @neubert yes tnx